# How to find the average (mean) of a column that occurred below the median of another column?

Tags: r

The whole question is to find the average (mean) magnitude of all earthquakes (column 1) that occurred below the median depth of all earthquakes(column 2).

I had the mean of column 1 and median of column 2 so far:

```
> median(quakes$depth)
[1] 247

   > mean(quakes$mag)
     [1] 4.6204
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "below the median depth".  Does it mean deeper than (more) or less than (more shallow) the median depth?

---

Either way, you can get an answer with the following, just switching `>` with `<` if necessary.

```
> mean(with(quakes, mag[depth > median(depth)]))
# [1] 4.5232
```

This gives the mean of the magnitudes such that the depth is greater (deeper) than the median depth.

Comment: And if I want to get the row(s) with the smallest value in a column, what should I do?

Comment: It depends on the column, but for `mag` it would be `quakes[with(quakes, mag == min(mag)),]`